# method elementAt() with index without listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get all elements from the map, if I need to use index without listView.builder?

I created the dropdown menu, and as I inderstood it creates the list with `map()` method for DropDownItem() widget. I am trying to use it, but get raw string data and it shouldn't be so. Also API is working on websockets and it returns Map like this `{2: GMT +02:00, 3: GMT +03:00}`, (it returns Object but I need to use as String)

So when I trying to put it in the UI without raw strings from API, I do it like this:

```
 items: snapshot.data?.values
                  .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: e,
                      child:
                          Text(snapshot.data?.values.elementAt(index) ?? '')))
                  .toList(),
```

So the question is, how can I use `elementAt()` method and put in it `index` without creating listview.builder to get the index of element? May be should I manipulate with `entries`? I was trying to create `int? index` , but it doesen't work.

If it is important, the length of elements is 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
items: snapshot.data?.values
                  .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: e,
                      child:
                          Text(snapshot.data?.values.elementAt(index) ?? '')))
                  .toList(),
```

Here `e` by itself is a single entry from the value. so you can use the same value here in child too like unless you wish to access index of some other element.

```
items: snapshot.data?.values
                  .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: e,
                      child:
                          Text(e.toString()??"")))
                  .toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List.generate`

```dart
DropdownButton(
    items: List.generate(values.length, (index) => ..),
```

Or for loop

```dart
DropdownButton(
  items: [
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
      DropdownMenuItem(child: child)
  ],
```